# Problem on Passwords (combination)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many four character passwords can be created using the characters A, B, C, D, 1, and 2, using each once, where the first two characters are letters?

I tried the following.......
1st position can have 4 possibilities (any of A,B,C,D),
2nd position can have 3 possibilities (any 3 of A,B,C,D, since one is used),
3rd position can have 4 possibilities(any 2 of A,B,C,D or 1,2), and
4th position can have 3 possibilities.(any one of A,B,C,D or 1,2)

so  $4 \times 3 \times 4 \times 3  = 144$ passwords can be created.
The answer given is $288$. How do they get that?

Comment: your logic looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

What you have done looks right to me. Could it be a mistake in the question? It says "using each once", which doesn't make sense if it is a 4-character password. You've assumed they meant "using each at most once", but it could be that it should have said "how many six-character passwords"; the answer to that would be $288$ (your argument for the first four characters, then there are $2$ choices for the fifth and $1$ for the sixth).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed  reply. I will try and get clarification on the question, which was as printed.Maybe it's an error.

Comment: It did get clarification and the answer is indeed 144, but was marked wrongly as 288.Thank you to all who replied.